# Exercise on uniqueness of smooth substructures from Warner 1.33(a)

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

If I understand correctly, the following is Theorem 1.32 of Warner's Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds book.

**Proposition.** Let $X\to Y$ be smooth and $\iota :A\to Y$ be an immersed submanifold. Suppose moreover $f(X)\subset\iota (A)$. By injectivity of $\iota$ there's a unique set function $f_0$ such that $\iota\circ f_0=f$.

1. $\iota$ is a topological embedding $\implies f_0$ continuous.
2. $f_0$ continuous $\implies f_0$ smooth.

In 1.33(a) we have the following assertion.

> Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold and $A\subset M$. Fix a topology on $A$. Then there is at most one differentiable structure on $A$ such that $\iota:A\hookrightarrow M$ is an injective immersion.

The hint is to apply Theorem 1.32, but I just don't see it. How to prove this result?

Comment: Hint on how to use the hint:  Take $Y = M$, $X = A$, and let $f$ and $i$ both be injective immersions.  Applying the hint gives a smooth $f_0:X\rightarrow A$.  Applying it again with the roles of $X$ and $A$ swapped gives a smooth $g_0:A\rightarrow X$...

Comment: @JasonDeVito where is the topological embedding ensuring the continuity of $g_0$?

Comment: I think I misread Theorem 1.32.  Sorry!

Comment: @JasonDeVito I think I'm the one missing something, because surely the solution you sketch is along the lines of what needs to happen. Would appreciate some insight!

Comment: I get it.  The map $f_0$ ends up being the identity map.  Since $X=A$ with fixed topology, it is continuous.  So you can use part b)

Comment: @JasonDeVito aw man. Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't need any reputation points, so please feel free to write up the answer in your own words.

Comment: @JasonDeVito don't think it can be formulated any better. Thanks again.